How to explode comma separated values in data frame using pyspark
I have data like the below :
ID               ID1                                  ID2
32336741        ["32361087"]                        ["36013040"]
32290433        ["32223150-32223653"]               ["36003347-36003348"]
32299856        ["32361087","32299991","32223653"]  ["36013040","36013029","36013040"]

In the Data frame I'm trying to explode the comma separated values into multiple rows.
code :
fulldf = (df
             .withColumn('ID1',F.explode(F.split('ID1','-')))
             .withColumn("ID1",F.regexp_replace("ID1", r"\[|\]|""\"", ""))
            )
fulldf = fulldf.dropna()
fulldf.display()

result :
ID              ID1
32336741        36013040
32290433        36003347
32290433        36003348
32290825        36013045
32290825        36013046
32290825        36013338

but when I add column ID2 in the data frame syntax it is giving me multiple records like doubled records.
expected out put :
ID                ID1       ID2
32336741        32361087  36013040
32290433        32223150  36003347
32290433        32223653  36003348
32290825        32361087  36013045
32290825        32299991  36013046
32290825        32223653  36013338


What is the expected output, if one row in the original dataframe does not have the same number of elements in columns ID1 and ID2? E.g. ID=1, ID1=[1,2] , ID2=[4,5,6]?

Instead of splitting etc. just extract numbers if what you show in example is consistent.
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
        (32336741,'["32361087"]','["36013040"]'),
        (32290433,'["32223150-32223653"]','["36003347-36003348"]'),
        (32299856,'["32361087","32299991","32223653"]','["36013040","36013029","36013040"]'),
    ], schema='id: int, id1: string, id2: string')


>>> df.select(F.regexp_extract_all(df.id1, F.lit('(\d+)'))).show(truncate=False)
+---------------------------------+
|regexp_extract_all(id1, (\d+), 1)|
+---------------------------------+
|[32361087]                       |
|[32223150, 32223653]             |
|[32361087, 32299991, 32223653]   |
+---------------------------------+

>>> df.select(F.explode(F.regexp_extract_all(df.id1, F.lit('(\d+)'))).alias('id1_split')).show()
+---------+
|id1_split|
+---------+
| 32361087|
| 32223150|
| 32223653|
| 32361087|
| 32299991|
| 32223653|
+---------+

>>>

Then depending on what you want you just need to join/cross-join original df with this exploded df to get what you want.

let me try and come back to you but  why you haven't added two columns. your output showing only one column

it is not working  if i add two columns

you need to update the question with what's expected, it's unclear, the input and output in question does not match. This answer shows you technique to use.
